# Django model class method using wrong `self`

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models

When I navigate to the admin page or my generic view for this model Loan I get the following error:

```
File "library_app/catalog/models.py", line 118, in __str__
return f'{self.book.title} ({self.id})'
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'title'
```

I've managed to track this down to the `__str__` function of my BookInstance class.

```
class Loan(models.Model):
book_instance = models.OneToOneField(BookInstance, on_delete=models.RESTRICT)
user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.RESTRICT)
date = models.DateField(
    default=django_timezone.now,
    help_text='Date borrowed'
)
due_back = models.DateField(
    default= django_timezone.now() + datetime.timedelta(30), 
    help_text='Date due to be returned'
)
returned_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True, help_text='Date book was returned')



class BookInstance(models.Model):
id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4)
book = models.ForeignKey(Book, on_delete=models.RESTRICT, null=True)

LOAN_STATUS = (
    ('m', 'Maintence'),
    ('o', 'On loan'),
    ('a', 'Available'),
    ('r', 'Reserved'),
)

status = models.CharField(
    max_length=1,
    choices=LOAN_STATUS,
    blank=True,
    default='m',
    help_text='Book Availability'
)

def __str__(self):
    return f'{self.book.title} ({self.id})'
```

I'm guessing that in these pages it when the `__str__` method is called the wrong `self` variable is being used. I have no idea how to fix this so any tips would be appreciated.

Comment: Well `book` has `null=True`, so `self.book`, can be `None`, it is however a bit odd to make this `null=True`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well book has `null=True`, so `self.book`, can be `None`, and therefore `self.book.title` does *not* per se makes sense.

In the `__str__` you thus will first have to check if there is indeed a linked `book` for that object, so:

```
class BookInstance(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4)
    book = models.ForeignKey(Book, on_delete=models.RESTRICT, null=True)
    LOAN_STATUS = (
        ('m', 'Maintence'),
        ('o', 'On loan'),
        ('a', 'Available'),
        ('r', 'Reserved'),
    )

    status = models.CharField(
        max_length=1,
        choices=LOAN_STATUS,
        blank=True,
        default='m',
        help_text='Book Availability',
    )

    def __str__(self):
        if self.book_id:
            return f'{self.book.title} ({self.id})'
        return str(self.id)
```

It is however a bit odd to make this `null=True`, that thus means there can be `BookInstance`s without a related `Book`? It might be better to clean the database and thus look for `BookInstance`s with `book=None`, fix these, and mark the field as non-nullable.

Comment: So in the end I decided that `book` should not have `null=True`